# React Router v6 Protected Routes Dynamic Index Page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nested-routes

I'm trying to create a dynamic "index" page whereby if the user is authenticated, the "/" route shows a dashboard component and if they are not authenticated, the "/" route shows a landing page; effectively having the same path for two different pages.

This is easy enough if I check whether the user is authenticated in the component itself; however, I'm trying to use nested routes.

The goal is: one set of public routes (e.g., "/", "/login", "/signup") and one set of private routes ("/", "/settings", "/profile") -- both of which are nested under the "/" route.

I'm just not sure how to achieve this using react router v6.

My Parent **Auth Route** is very simple:

```
import { routeConstants } from '@src/constants';
import { useAuth } from '@src/hooks';
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthRouter = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to={routeConstants.Routes.LogIn} replace />;
  }

  return <Outlet />;
};

export default AuthRouter;
```

**App.ts**

```
      {/* Private Routes */}
      <Route element={<AuthRouter />}>
        <Route path={RouteConstants.Index} element={<Pages.Home />} />
      </Route>
```

I just can't seem to render a different "/" page based on auth status using nested routes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the issue correctly you are asking how to have a root home page route that conditionally renders one of two components depending on the auth status while protecting several sub-routes. For this you'll use a separate layout route specifically for the root index route that handles the "either or" conditional rendering of the landing or dashboard components. The `AuthRoute` component will handle protecting the authenticated routes.

Example:

```
const AuthRoute = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  if (user === undefined) {
    return null;
  }

  return user
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

```
const AuthOrUnauth = ({ AuthElement, UnauthElement }) => {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  return user ? AuthElement : UnauthElement;
};
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    index
    element={(
      <AuthOrUnauth
        AuthElement={<Dashboard />}
        UnauthElement={<Landing />}
      />
    )}
  />
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route path="/signup" element={<Register />} />
  <Route element={<AuthRoute />}>
    <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} />
    <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

### Demo

[image: Edit react-router-v6-protected-routes-dynamic-index-page]